# How can a zip-file via NSIS be unzipped and the NSIS-scriptfile into folder be executed automatically?

Tags: nsis

I am writting a NSIS-script for installs of the programs and put into folder. The folder is zipped via NSIS. I want, that someone clicks once the zip-file and it will be unzipped and executed the NSIS-script into folder. But how?

Update: I explain again. NSIS has the compiler for NSIS script and Installer based on ZIP! Firstly, I write a NSIS script to install some programs in a folder. Executing the NSIS script is working! I dont want to send the folder, but I want to send only one file. So I am using the Installer based on ZIP to zip the folder. But if I click the zipped file, it will be unzipped on desktop without executing the NSIS script into folder. So I have to click the NSIS script into folder. That I dont want! I want to click only on zipped file and it will be unzipped and executed automatically the NSIS script. Clearly?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do, could you post some of the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

`.zip` files cannot execute code.

NOTE: The ZIP2EXE NSIS tool uses makensis internally, it is just a helper application that creates simple installers.

Comment: The ZIP2EXE NSIS Tool can not execute the NSIS script into the folder, or? It convert only from zip-files to basic installers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but I believe that what you want to do is create a self extracting archive that contains multiple files and run and NSIS installer contained in that archive it is unpacked.

You can do this with 7zip.

It's easiest to do this with a dos batch file. Open notepad and create `"selfinstall.bat"`

Add the following;

```
(
  ECHO ;!@Install@!UTF-8!
  ECHO Title="My Installer"
  ECHO BeginPrompt="Do you want to run the installer?"
  ECHO ExecuteFile="Setup.exe"
  ECHO ;!@InstallEnd@!
) > temp.$$$
```

This sets up the information that the self extracter needs such as it's title (My Installer) and the name of the executable to run (Setup.exe)

Then, add the lines to create your zip file

```
7z a -r files.7z myfolder
```

where myfolder is the name of the folder that has all the files.

Now, add the installer - Make sure that the installer (Setup.exe) is in the root of the .7z file

```
7z a files.7z Setup.exe
```

Then, copy the self extracter and the 7z to a single executable file

```
copy /b 7z.sfx + temp.$$$ + files.7z "Install.exe"
```

Then delete your temp files

```
del files.7z
del temp.$$$
```

I adapted this from a script I saw here; http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=18845
For more information on the .SFX modules see here; http://7zsfx.info/en/

There's also a sourceforge project for a GUI to accomplish this; http://sourceforge.net/projects/sfx-maker/